# LINQ and 2 datatables

Tags: linq

I have 2 datatables in a dataset. One table has a list called CostTypes. Just an Id and Description field.

The other datatable is the master table and has many records and one of the columns is the cost type. There will be cost types that are not reference in this datatable. There is another column in this databale called cost.

What I am trying to do is get a summary by cost type with a total of the cost. But I want ALL cost types listed any values not in the master table will be zero.

CostType table

```
Id, Description

1,Marketing

2,Sales

3,Production

4,Service
```

---

```
Master table

Id, Cost, CostTypeId

1,10,1

2,120,1

3,40,3
```

So I would like to see a result in a datable (if possible) so I can bind to datagridview

```
Marketing  130

Sales       0

Production  40

Service     0
```

Thanks for the help everyone, this is what I came up from the answers - Can anyone suggest any improvements???

**Also how can I convert the result in query1 into a datable???**

```
  var query1 =
        from rowCT in costTypes.AsEnumerable()
        from rowSTD in stdRates.AsEnumerable()
              .Where( d => d.Field<int?>( "CostTypeId" ) == rowCT.Field<int?>( "CostTypeId" ) )
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
        group new { row0 = rowCT, row1 = rowSTD }
        by rowCT.Field<string>( "Description" ) into g
        select new
        {
            g.Key,
            Cost = g.Sum( x => x.row1 == null ? 0 : x.row1.Field<decimal>( "Cost" ) ),
            TotalCost = g.Sum( x => x.row1 == null ? 0 : x.row1.Field<decimal>( "TotalCost" ) ),
            TotalHours = g.Sum( x => x.row1 == null ? 0 : x.row1.Field<decimal>( "TotalHours" ) ),
            TotalLabourCost = g.Sum( x => x.row1 == null ? 0 : x.row1.Field<decimal>( "TotalLabourCost" ) )
        }
        ;
```

Comment: In my answer I have code that demonstrates how you can create a `DataTable` as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data:**

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Description",typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1,"Marketing");
dt.Rows.Add(2,"Sales");
dt.Rows.Add(3,"Production");
dt.Rows.Add(4,"Service");

DataTable dt2=new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("Cost",typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("CostTypeId",typeof(int));

dt2.Rows.Add(1,10,1);
dt2.Rows.Add(2,120,1);
dt2.Rows.Add(3,40,1);
```

**Linq query**

```
var query=(
            from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            from row1 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where (d =>d.Field<int>("Id")==row.Field<int>("Id") )
                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new{row,row1} 
            by row.Field<string>("Description") into g 
            select new
            {
                g.Key,
                Cost=g.Sum (x =>x.row1==null?0:x.row1.Field<int>("Cost"))
            }
            );
```

**Result**

```
Key        Cost
Marketing  10
Sales      120
Production 40
Service    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Sum` extension method to compute the cost. It will return 0 if the collection is empty which is exactly what you want:

```
var costTypes = new DataTable("CostTypes");
costTypes.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
costTypes.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));
costTypes.Rows.Add(1, "Marketing");
costTypes.Rows.Add(2, "Sales");
costTypes.Rows.Add(3, "Production");
costTypes.Rows.Add(4, "Service");

var costEntries = new DataTable("CostEntries");
costEntries.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
costEntries.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(Int32));
costEntries.Columns.Add("CostTypeId", typeof(Int32));
costEntries.Rows.Add(1, 10, 1);
costEntries.Rows.Add(2, 120, 1);
costEntries.Rows.Add(3, 40, 3);

var costs = costTypes
  .Rows
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(
    dr => new {
      Id = dr.Field<Int32>("Id"),
      Description = dr.Field<String>("Description")
    }
  )
  .Select(
    ct => new {
      ct.Description,
      TotalCost = costEntries
        .Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .Where(ce => ce.Field<Int32>("CostTypeId") == ct.Id)
        .Sum(ce => ce.Field<Int32>("Cost"))
    }
  );
```

The result is:

```
Description|TotalCost
-----------+---------
Marketing  |      130
Sales      |        0
Production |       40
Service    |        0
```

You can create a new `DataSet` quite simply:

```
var costsDataTable = new DataTable("Costs");
costsDataTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));
costsDataTable.Columns.Add("TotalCost", typeof(Int32));
foreach (var cost in costs)
  costsDataTable.Rows.Add(cost.Description, cost.TotalCost);
```

If the linear search performed by the `Where` in the code above is a concern you can improve the performance by creating a lookup table in advance:

```
var costEntriesLookup = costEntries
  .Rows
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(
    ce => new {
      Cost = ce.Field<Int32>("Cost"),
      CostTypeId = ce.Field<Int32>("CostTypeId")
    }
  )
  .ToLookup(ce => ce.CostTypeId, ce => ce.Cost);
var costs = costTypes
  .Rows
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(
    dr => new {
      Id = dr.Field<Int32>("Id"),
      Description = dr.Field<String>("Description")
    }
  )
  .Select(
    ct => new {
      ct.Description,
      TotalCost = costEntriesLookup.Contains(ct.Id)
        ? costEntriesLookup[ct.Id].Sum()
        : 0
    }
  );
```

Comment: I just think that you are missing the point. The OP has two datatables and he wants to use them. How do your answer apply to that?

Comment: My goal was to demonstrate how to use `Sum` to perform the calculation. However, to better answer the question I have changed my code to use datatables.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simpler bit of linq than others seemed to use. Thanks to Martin Liversage for the code to create the input data.

```
var costTypes = new DataTable("CostTypes");
costTypes.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
costTypes.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));
costTypes.Rows.Add(1, "Marketing");
costTypes.Rows.Add(2, "Sales");
costTypes.Rows.Add(3, "Production");
costTypes.Rows.Add(4, "Service");

var costEntries = new DataTable("CostEntries");
costEntries.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
costEntries.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(Int32));
costEntries.Columns.Add("CostTypeId", typeof(Int32));
costEntries.Rows.Add(1, 10, 1);
costEntries.Rows.Add(2, 120, 1);
costEntries.Rows.Add(3, 40, 3);

var cte = costTypes.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var cee = costEntries.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var output = cte.Select(
ct => new {
    Description = ct["Description"], 
    Sum = cee.Where(ce=>ce["CostTypeId"].Equals(ct["Id"])).Sum(ce=>(int)ce["Cost"])
    }

);
```

This may lose efficiency on larger tables since each cost type will search the cost entry table whereas using grouping I suspect you only need one pass over the table. Personally I'd prefer the (to my mind) simpler looking code. It will depend on your use case though.